# What's the deal with the "get" prefix for value methods?

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

Hi I'm new to salesforce and force.com but I am a coder so I am comfortable learning new languages.

What I'm not comfortable with is the "get" prefix that I can't find a reference to in the docs. (At least I haven't found it yet - but I would think it was so important it deserves a mention). What I'm referring to is this kind of thing....

```
<!--Page excerpt-->
<apex:outputLabel value="My Stupidness:" for="Stupids" />
<apex:selectList id="Stupids" size="1" value="{!crap}" required="false">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="selacct" />
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SomethingStupid}"/>
</apex:selectList>


/* Code excerpt */
public List<SelectOption> getSomethingStupid() {
    List<SelectOption> things = new List<SelectOption>();
    things.add(new SelectOption('bike','1'));
    things.add(new SelectOption('car','2'));
    return things;
}
```

This works by the way.

So I set `value="{!SomethingStupid}"` but the method in the code *isn't called that!* It's called `getSomethingStupid` - And it appears that it must have the `get` prefix.

I suppose I can live with this although I find it a bit weird. I would find it significantly less weird if I could find anyone else or any documentation mentioning this fact or any of the reasoning etc behind it? For example is it always necessary for controls that retrieve data? Is there a similar rule for `set`?

I feel like I'm living in the twilight zone and everyone else is oblivious to this!

Comment: Its documented here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm

Comment: Isn't that how Java does it? Apex is just a custom Java implementation, after all.

Comment: It's certainly something to get used to. I didn't have a Java background and this frustrated me when I was learning.

Comment: Also, `setValue()` is used to make `{!value}` writable.

Comment: I think it is the same thing in View frameworks on the Java Platform. To be Java Bean compliant every attribute needs a getter and a setter and inside a page you always access it just by referencing the attributes name.

Comment: @MikeChale I certainly don't think it's a bog-standard Java feature, I don't ever recall seeing it when I was learning Java (although I never spent that long with Java) - and it's not something I've come across reading example etc. It seems like a case of [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) which by the sounds of it appeared with whole Beans thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public List<SelectOption> getSomethingStupid() {
    List<SelectOption> things = new List<SelectOption>();
    things.add(new SelectOption('bike','1'));
    things.add(new SelectOption('car','2'));
    return things;
}
```

is the same thing as:

```
public List<SelectOption> somethingStupid {
    get {
        somethingStupid = new List<SelectOption>();
        somethingStupid.add(new SelectOption('bike','1'));
        somethingStupid.add(new SelectOption('car','2'));
        return somethingStupid;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I would also add that getters/setters fit more naturally into the lazy loading paradigm:

```
public List<SelectOption> somethingStupid {
    get {
        if (somethingStupid == null) {
            somethingStupid = new List<SelectOption>();
            somethingStupid.add(new SelectOption('bike','1'));
            somethingStupid.add(new SelectOption('car','2'));
        }
        return somethingStupid;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm more comfortable with the second approach although I'm going to go with the naming-convention one just to fit in!

Answer (score 7):

The method name prefixes are just part of the language, part of life.

They're really easy to use once you get the hang of it.  The idea is this: external classes need special syntax to access your controller class's variables -- to be able to read values and to write values to those variables.  Hence we have "getters" and "setters".

"Getters" are used when an external class wants to know the information of a controller variable.  Think:

> "Get me the value of this variable."

"Setters" are used to set a controller variable.  Think:

> "Set the value of this variable to that."

When you define controller variables, you have a few options.  First, you can use the standard get and set methods.  To initialize the variable, you can set its value in the initialization.

Example 1:

```
public class myController{

    public string Username {get;set;}

    public myController(){
        Username = 'myCustomInitialization';
    }//END init

}//end Class
```

Second, suppose you want to display a custom picklist of Accounts that have the custom checkbox Able_to_View__c = true.  Also, let's have the "selectedAccount" initialized as the first Account on the list.  You can do the following:

Example 2:

```
public class myController{

    public list<selectOption> accountList {
        get{
            list<selectOption> returnList=new list<selectOption>();

            for(Account a:[SELECT id, Name FROM Account WHERE Able_to_View__c=true])
                returnList.add(new selectOption(a.id,a.Name));

            return returnList;
        }
        set;}

    public string selectedAccount {get;set;}

    public myController(){
        if(!accountList.isEmpty())
            selectedAccount=accountList[0].getValue();
    }//END init

}//end Class
```

This definitely works, but it's good to note that every time accountList is called, it executes the "get" code.  This may be too cumbersome for certain applications.  Also, in this example, it might not be necessary to change the accountList from your VF page (i.e. use the "set" method).  In this case, we may only write the get method but in a slightly different way.

Example 3:

```
public class myController{

    public string selectedAccount {get;set;}

    public myController(){
        if(!getAccountList.isEmpty())
            selectedAccount=getAccountList[0].getValue();
    }//END init

    public list<selectOption> getAccountList(){
        list<selectOption> returnList=new list<selectOption>();

        for(Account a:[SELECT id, Name FROM Account WHERE Able_to_View__c=true])
            returnList.add(new selectOption(a.id,a.Name));

        return returnList;
    }//END getAccountList

}//END Class
```

While this code still executes the method "getAccountList" every time it is called, it's a little cleaner.  To save some execution, you can save the "AccountList" as a private variable, create it once, and then just reference it if needed.

Example 4:

```
public class myController{

    public string selectedAccount {get;set;}
    private list<selectOption> acctList;

    public myController(){
        if(!getAccountList.isEmpty())
            selectedAccount=getAccountList[0].getValue();
    }//END init

    public list<selectOption> getAccountList(){
        if(acctList==null){
            acctList=new list<selectOption>();

            for(Account a:[SELECT id, Name FROM Account WHERE Able_to_View__c=true])
            acctList.add(new selectOption(a.id,a.Name));
        }
        return acctList;
    }//END getAccountList

}//END Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought it was as a ***simplification*** the APEX designers made over JAVA to make it easier for non-developers, non-object-oriented Java people to understand APEX in the context of Visualforce.

Answer (score 1):

More current documentation link to anyone following this thread - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm